# I am implementing a LinkedList using python and want to check the length of the node but node.length() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Implementation is added as image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEvkw.png)> I declared variable as

> > > node:LinkedList=None

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,val=None,next:"LinkedList"=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def addAtHead(self, val: int):
        global node
        new_node = LinkedList(val)
        if not node:
            node = new_node
            return
        tmp = node
        new_node.next = node
        node = new_node
        return

    def length(self):
        global node
        ans = 0
        root = node
        while root:
            ans+=1
            root = root.next
        return ans
node:LinkedList = None
print(node.length())
```

Comment: Saying that code is "not working" doesn't tell us anything.  Instead, tell us what the code _actually does_, and explain how that's different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: Don't post code as images.  That just makes it harder for us to help.

Comment: I wanted the output of node.length() as 0 But it throwing error.

Comment: Show us the error.  Otherwise we're only guessing at the problem.

Comment: `node` is None.  Why do you expect a `None` object to have a `.length()` method?

Comment: Code is now added.

Comment: I declared node as LinkedList as None. Same as C++ type.

Comment: If this is incorrect then is there any method through which i can check the length when length is zero.

Comment: _I declared node as LinkedList as None. Same as C++ type_ This isn't C++.  Python doesn't work like that.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this functionality in python?

Comment: Why `global node`? You shouldn't need a global variable to determine the length of a list.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I figured another way of doing this .I can make define length function outside the class and pass node(LinkedList object) as param. I know this is not what I wanted

Comment: And if length method is class attribute then while calling the length for the first time I can call LinkedList.length(node). This is also working.